# Why does my program not return 0 in an if statement?

Tags: c++

My program is not returning `0` when I press `n` when it asks me if I want to accept the charges.

I want the program to stop when I press `n` and run the $25 charge when I press `y`

Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double InitialAmount, WithdrawAmount; 

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

    cout << "Deposite initial amount: ";
    cin >> InitialAmount;
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cin >> InitialAmount;
        cout << "Invalid initial amount" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if (InitialAmount < 0)
    {
        cout << "Balance under 0, cannot withdraw" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Enter an amount to withdraw: ";
    cin >> WithdrawAmount;
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cin >> WithdrawAmount;
        cout << "Invalid withdraw amount" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if (WithdrawAmount > 500)
    {
        cout << "Cannot withdraw this amount" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    double YesFees, InsufFees;

    if (InitialAmount > 1 and WithdrawAmount > InitialAmount)
    {
        cout << "Insufficient funds for this withdrawal There will be a $25.00 service charge. Would you like to continue? (Y/N): ";
        cin >> InsufFees;


        if (InsufFees == 'y')
        {
            YesFees = 25;
        }

       if (InsufFees == 'n')
       {
          return 0;
       }

    }

    double fees;
    if (WithdrawAmount > 300)
    {
        fees = WithdrawAmount * .04;
    }

    cout << left << setw(20) << setfill('.') << "Amount withdrawn";
    cout << "$" << setw(10) << setfill (' ') << right << WithdrawAmount << endl;
    cout << left << setw(20) << setfill('.') << "Amount of fees";
    cout << "$" << setw(10) << setfill (' ') << right << fees + YesFees << endl;
    cout << left << setw(20) << setfill('.') << "Balance";
    cout << "$" << setw(10) << setfill (' ') << right << InitialAmount - WithdrawAmount - YesFees - fees  << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but you aren't reliably initializing `fees` before printing it out.  I assume you want to initialize it to `0.0`;

Comment: `InsufFees` is a double, it won't ever contain `y` or `n`. You should check to be sure your input succeeds, like `if(cin >> foo) { ... }`

Comment: Unrelated: You probably want a `while` instead of an `if` here: `if (cin.fail())`, because a talented enough user can screw up more than once. Plus you will have to `clear` the error flag and `ignore` the rejected input.

Comment: Unrelated neat trick: You see how you have chained `<<`s in `cout << left << setw(20) << setfill('.') << "Amount withdrawn";`? You can keep on chaining and get rid of the `cout`s on the following lines. I don't think you gain anything, but it's still a neat trick.

Answer (score 2):

The `InsufFees` variable is of type `double`, so `cin` is failing when it tries to read a character. You need to change the type of `InsufFees` to `char`:

```
char InsufFees;
cin >> InsufFees;
```